# Why is my React functional component breaking my GSAP animation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I'm currently developing a Gatbsy website using GSAP for all of the animation, however I've come across the following issue.

I have a simple component called *CrossFade.tsx* which contains two images and a range input that changes the image opacity.

When I insert this component into a page, it breaks any GSAP animation BELOW it and causes them to jump, until I resize the viewport at which point it then works as expected. I therefore suspect it's something to do with the load of the component.

This only happens when I have the following component ABOVE any animated component within the respective page view.

CrossFade.tsx

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import StandardImage from '../Images/StandardImage';
import ThemeContext from '../../context/ThemeContext';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface ICrossFadeImagesProps {
  image1: string;
  image2: string;
}

const RangeSlider = styled.input`
  ...
`;

const CrossFadeImages: FunctionComponent<ICrossFadeImagesProps> = ({
  image1,
  image2,
}: ICrossFadeImagesProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="relative">
        <div className="absolute inset-0 z-20" style={{ opacity: value }}>
          <StandardImage src={image1} className="w-full" />
        </div>
        <StandardImage src={image2} className="w-full" />
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-center mt-4">
        <RangeSlider
          theme={theme}
          type="range"
          min="0"
          max="1"
          step="0.01"
          value={value}
          onChange={({ target }) => setValue(target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CrossFadeImages;
```

ProjectPage.tsx

```
const ProjectPage: FunctionComponent = (): ReactElement => {
  useEffect(() => {
    
  });

  return (
    <Layout>
      <ProjectHero>
        <Video url={HeroVideo} />
      </ProjectHero>
      {/* This is the component causing the ScrollTrigger to lose it's correct start position */}
      <CrossFadeImages />
      {/* This is the GSAP ScrollTrigger component */}
      <ScrollImages images={ScrollImages} />
    </Layout>
  );
};
export default ProjectPage;
```

ScrollImages.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import ScrollImage from '../Images/ScrollImage';
import { gsap, ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/all';

interface ScrollImagesProps {
  images: Image[];
  bg?: string;
}
interface Image {
  projectImg: string;
}

const ScrollImages: React.FunctionComponent<ScrollImagesProps> = ({
  images,
}: ScrollImagesProps) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
    let scrollWrapper = ref.current.querySelector('.wrapper');
    let container = ref.current.querySelector('.container');
    gsap.to(scrollWrapper, {
      x: -(scrollWrapper.scrollWidth - container.offsetWidth),
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ref.current,
        start: 'center center',
        pin: true,
        scrub: true,
        invalidateOnRefresh: true,
        anticipatePin: 1,
      },
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <section ref={ref}>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="wrapper w-full flex flex-nowrap">
          {images.map((x, i) => (
            <ScrollImage
              key={`project-img-${i}`}
              src={x.projectImg}
              className={`flex-shrink-0 border border-primary border-opacity-20 ${
                i != 0 ? 'ml-8' : ''
              }`}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
export default ScrollImages;
```

Comment: When you say "it breaks any GSAP animation BELOW it and causes them to jump" are you talking about it breaking any *ScrollTriggered* animations below it? If so, it's likely because the ScrollTriggers have been initiated before the images have loaded. So their original locations are off and it has no knowledge of things changing. Adding `ScrollTrigger.refresh()` after the images have loaded should fix the issue.

Comment: Hi Zach - that's exactly the issue I'm having. I've just updated my question with the component containing the ScrollTrigger code. Perhaps you could kindly advise as to where I should place the ScrollTrigger.refresh()? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), perhaps using CodeSandbox, of the issue?

Comment: I managed to solve but thanks anyway! It was an issue rendering SVG's, as soon as I used pngs/jpegs it fixed the issue.